# How to program this STM32F401 with a blink program?

Tags: stm32

I bought this STM32F https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4001049840288.html?spm=a2g0o.order_list.order_list_main.88.4f9118025KlvjN but I have no idea how to program it. There are ISP mode, DFU mode, and serial mode. Which one do I need to code this?

I already installed https://github.com/stlink-org/stlink but I get

```
sudo st-info --serial
libusb: error [submit_bulk_transfer] submiturb failed, errno=2
[!] send_recv send request failed: LIBUSB_ERROR_IO
...
```

Is there a way to flash it with a blink program through USB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DFU mode may not work reliably on those modules due to the choice of a too-high crystal frequency in the design. Hence the text in the ad you linked referring to heating the chip, which is not really a normal procedure for flashing program memory.

I suggest you procure an STLINK V2 (it is a piece of  hardware that plugs into a USB port) and use that to program the module via the 4-pin header.

Comment: can I stull use stliknk's github stuff to code with this? I found this one https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004428192100.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.6cae763fHf92QN&algo_pvid=f185ea22-8f08-46d0-aa80-ec8eed0bef8b&algo_exp_id=f185ea22-8f08-46d0-aa80-ec8eed0bef8b-2&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2212000029151192146%22%7D&pdp_npi=2%40dis%21BRL%2115.96%2111.17%21%21%21%21%21%40210318bb16708507057822164eb412%2112000029151192146%21sea&curPageLogUid=vmhJ1XPtB4kU

Comment: Yes, that’s the kind of device. I can’t speak to the particular software you refer to, but I would expect it to work when properly used.